# react button scroll to particular div

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I am developing a react website at the top I have `navbar`, with logo in the left, nav links on the center, and "need home tutor" `button` in the right whenever users click this button I want to scroll to contact us `<div> </div>`.

**here is what I tried: -** i.e my navbar.js

```
  <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul className="navbar-nav navbar-right" id="mySidenav">
              <li className="nav-item active">
                <a href="#home" className="nav-link">
                  Home
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a href="#services" className="nav-link">
                  Services
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a href="#features" className="nav-link">
                  About Us
                </a>
              </li>
              {/* <li className="nav-item">
                <a href="#pricing" className="nav-link">
                  Pricing
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a href="#team" className="nav-link">
                  Team
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a href="#blog" className="nav-link">
                  Blog
                </a>
              </li> */}
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a href="#contact" className="nav-link">
                  Contact us
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div className="nav-button ml-auto">
              <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="btn btn-custom navbar-btn btn-rounded waves-effect waves-light"
                    onClick={scrollToBottom}
                  >
                    Need home tutor ?
                  </button>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

**onScroll handler :-**

```
const scrollToBottom = () => {
  window.scroll({
    bottom: document.body.scrollHeight, // 
    left: 0,
    behavior: "smooth",
  });
};
```

Comment: you can use `node.scrollIntoView()`

Comment: thanks it worked do u know how can i achieve 'smooth' scroll , i have tried the scrollOption={} but i couldnt achieve it?

Comment: you can pass additional props like this `node.scrollIntoView({block: 'end', behavior: 'smooth'})`

Comment: sorry its scrolling fast , idk why but i will figure out . thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://robinvdvleuten.nl/blog/scroll-a-react-component-into-view/

You can use `scrollIntoView()` and `useRef()` for scrolling specific elementa.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
node.scrollIntoView({block: "start", behavior: "smooth"})
```

See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView